# Request origin from mobile app

Tags: android, meteor

I am new in meteor i have developed one application which is call third party api and its working fine in my website. i have made application from my OSX machine with live website url with following command 
meteor ~/androidapp build --server=https://example.com

and my app started successfully everything works fine except my third party api.

Please note my thrid party api also authenticating request origin. i am not able to figure out that what is the request origin of mobile app with above command i have set ROOT_URL as a env variable in my OSX machine which is same available at my EC2 server

Please try to figure out what is the problem

Comment: it's a bit hard to see what the problem is that you are trying to solve. Could you phrase it as a question?

Comment: I want to know mobile app request origin because my third party api authenticating my request origin also. and they are telling me that your request origin is different then you register. so i want to register mobile app request origin. I am thinking its http://meteor.local i am not sure about this

Comment: @ChristianFritz please visit this url for my full explanation and answer as you have given me nagative point https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4770#issuecomment-123171098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://meteor.local/ is a mobile app request origin and when i register this url with third party api and my code is working fine. Please visit github thread in which i give example of my problem

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4770#issuecomment-123171098